# Select strokes from inkcanvas within a rectangle by program

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, inkcanvas

I have an InkCanvas with strokes present. I wish to use only the strokes, or part of the strokes, that fall within a given region. In short, I wish to clip any ink outside of this region. I can't figure out how to cast this correctly:

```
            Rect r = new Rect(100,100,100,100);

            StrokeCollection x = InkCanvas.Strokes
                .Select(s => s.GetClipResult(r));
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now? According to documentation that is what you would need

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection>' to 'System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ method `Select<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and you are attempting to assign it to x which is not `IEnumerable<T>` type. so the correct syntax would be

```
IEnumerable<StrokeCollection> x = InkCanvas.Strokes.Select(s => s.GetClipResult(r));
```

and if you wish to have to have first collection then x.First() or x.FirstOrDefault() will return the first StrokeCollection from the `IEnumerable<StrokeCollection>` where former will throw exception if it is empty and latter will return null which is default for reference type StrokeCollection.

**Retrieve all strokes in a new stroke collection**

the LINQ can be modified to

```
StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection(InkCanvas.Strokes.SelectMany(s => s.GetClipResult(r)));
```

this will retrieve all the strokes from the clip region and create a new StrokeCollection with them.

Comment: Thank you. That does answer my question. But what I would like is linq code that does this:  StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection();
                foreach (Stroke s in InkCanvas.Strokes)
                {
                    StrokeCollection rs = s.GetClipResult(r);
                    strokes.Add(rs);
                }

Comment: I updated my answer for your requirement so you can use a single LINQ hence you need not to do a for each and add them individually.

Comment: I am glad it work for you. You may also choose to vote up the answer to keep it on the top.